# Optimising a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

people

My project has a social media stream which loads paged objects and also pulls to refresh. I am using an MGScrollView which extends UIScrollView and I am wondering how I can optimise it. The issue is that after hundreds of items are loaded into the stream, it will become quite a memory hog.

It's not really possible to use a page pattern as all my content varies in size. The items that appear can vary in complexity and number of sub views. Added to that, because of the pull to refresh feature, items can pop into the top of the stream making dropping and adding items on/off screen pretty tricky.

Does anyone know of any sweet project I can leverage to help me do this?

Files attached of stream screen dumped from the app itself:

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try adding features (animation and pull to refresh) to UITableView instead of optimising the scrollview. TableView is the solution of memory issues on scroll view. But of course that will make you use more cpu.

I think, if you use table view, your cells' height will be dynamic. For performance concern, you can check this article about twitter's iOS application.

[ehttp://engineering.twitter.com/2012/02/simple-strategies-for-smooth-animation.html](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/02/simple-strategies-for-smooth-animation.html)

Comment: Does it matter than that the table won't really have any reusable cells?

Comment: It matters for memory. It will reuse the cells.

Comment: Good article. Thanks I'll have a go with tables.